# Bootstrap table non-removable border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap table for displaying some simple info, but I'm having a weird issue.

When I use the `bootstrap-table` stylesheet the table appears the way I want it, i.e. with no outer border, but when I initialize the stylesheet the entire table gets this weird outline, that I can't seem to remove – even though adding borderless to the class.

*Without CSS file:*
[image: Without CSS file]

*With CSS file:*
[image: With CSS file]

*HTML:*

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table id="table" class="table table-dark table-responsive table-no-bordered">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th data-field="id">#</th>
            <th data-field="filename">#</th>
            <th data-field="type">#</th>
            <th data-field="comment">#</th>
            <th data-field="action">#</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr></tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: response_Array,
    pagination: true,
    pageSize: 5
});
$('.fixed-table-loading').remove();

});
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e.g. use [https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/)) so we can run your code and modify or even post some example code?

Comment: Can try to setup one, I get data from a database though which might make it tricky. I will update the OP with some of my code that might be relevant though!

Comment: Can you post the CSS that's being applied? Hard for us to figure out where the border is coming from without the relevant style rules. Posting the CSS snippets for all of `table table-dark table-responsive table-no-bordered` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the bootstrapTable example from [here](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/from-data.html) the corresponding css class which causes the border is `.fixed-table-container`.

Try to add this to your javascript:

```
$('.fixed-table-container').css('border', 'none');
```

Hopefully it works. Alternatively you can try to use inline or external css:

```
<style>
    .fixed-table-container {
        border: none;  // or border: none !important;
    }
</style>
```